# Arithmetic overflow error only when join condition exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Having an odd issue converting a decimal to a varchar. Here is the format of the conversion for final SELECT that when executed, causes an"Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar." error:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 4), Distribution.Rate))
```

The largest value returned in the dataset is 351.1800. The Rate column is setup as DEC(15,4), but the spec for the file we need is rated at 9,4.

The odd thing is that on the Distribution table we have another table joined to it on ID, and that joined table has a condition on it to limit results to primary-flagged records only (Nothing to do with Rate).

```
JOIN LaborDistribution ON LaborDistribution.ID = Distribution.LaborDistributionID
    AND LaborDistribution.IsPrimary = 1
```

When I remove the IsPrimary condition on the joined table, the script runs fine with no errors. Note that if I move that condition to the WHERE clause, the error persists just the same as it does when included on the JOIN.

Any idea why a conditional table join completely unrelated to this value would cause this issue? We are resolving it for now by bumping up the precision, but we are scratching our heads on the conditions that are causing the error.

Comment: *Note that if I move that condition to the WHERE clause, it has the same effect* error? or no error?

Comment: Some numbers have more than 5 digits in left side. that's why the error disappear when you remove the join. So, you need to increase the varchar limit to 15 and then adjust the results from there.

Comment: Simonare - That was positioned and worded poorly. Putting it in the WHERE statement resulted in the same error as if it were part of the join.

Comment: iSR5 - The max value I am dealing with is 351.1800 regardless of the JOIN or the condition. The question is why the the condition causes the error on the same data set that returns fine when the condition is removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 4), Distribution.Rate))
```

Let say that your value is `12345.6789`

when you convert this value to varchar you actually need 10 characters long field (pay attention to decimal seperator)

```
VARCHAR(10)
```

will solve your issue

Comment: But, you will see in my OP that the max value returned in my dataset is 351.1800, which is only 8 characters. I understand the error in its raw form when the length of the value exceeds the defined precision, but that by itself isn't the problem we are trying to get to the bottom of.

Answer (score 1):

*"Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar."* can be the result from [explicit or implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-and-explicit-conversion) data type conversion.

Your statement `CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 4), Distribution.Rate))` will cause an explicit data type conversion error when

`Distribution.Rate <= -1000` for negative values (additional char for sign) or

`Distribution.Rate >= 10000` for positive values.

You may try to find these values with:

```
SELECT Distribution.Rate
FROM Distribution
WHERE (Distribution.Rate <= -1000.0) OR (Distribution.Rate >= 10000.0)
```

Implicit conversions are not visible to the user and in your case this type of conversion maybe the reason to receive this error after JOIN statement. SQL Server do conversion based on [Data Type Precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Numeric values have a higher precedence compared to nvarchar(varchar) values, so in implicit conversions the nvarchar(varchar) values are converted to numeric.

Comment: Interesting insight Zhorov. The only reason that we are converting to VARCHAR is that we are building a delimited string with many (30+) different values. The script was built years ago but perhaps now that the client is on SQL2017 we will just look into using CONCAT so we don't have to include all these conversions and perhaps that will avoid any future issues with these precedence rules. Thanks!